# DateTime Modify() php affecting previous variable

Tags: php, datetime, variables

So I'm having a weird issue with DateTimes modify() function.

I start off with a DateTime eg: 2018-08-07 12:00 & a number of days to add eg: 2.

I copy the dateTime (in variable $startDt) to a new variable ($date) so its not affected by any changes.

The modify function works fine. I get 2018-08-09 12:00. But then I want to repeat the action with a new number but the same start date. Say +3.

But it adds a total of 5! I checked and when using modify() on $date; it somehow also changes $startDt.

Can someone explain this miracle to me? :)) How does applying a function to Variable 2 affect Variable 1? Even if Variable 2 was initially a clone of Variable 1; they are supposed to be 2 separate entities...

```
while ($x < $duration) {

        $date = $startDt;
        echo "$startDt before:" . $startDt->format('Y-m-d') . "<br>";
        $date = $date->modify('+' . $x . 'day');
        echo "$startDt after:" . $startDt->format('Y-m-d') . "<br>";

        $x++;

    }
```

Results:

```
$startDt before +2 : 2018-08-08
$startDt after: 2018-08-10
$startDt before +3 : 2018-08-10
$startDt after: 2018-08-13
```

Comment: *I copy the dateTime (in variable $startDt) to a new variable ($date) so its not affected by any changes.* - unfortunately that isn't how it works. When you copy an object variable like this, all you're doing is creating another pointer to the same object. If you want an entirely separate object instance then use [`clone`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php), or alternatively you can use the [`DateTimeImmutable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) class.

Comment: Seems like all you're doing is just adding days on? so as you add 2 it will go up to the 10th, and then adding 3 to the 10th will make it the 13th

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When assigning `$startDt` to `$date` the value isn't copied but referenced instead. You need to explicitly copy the object into the other variable:

```
# referenced
$date = $startDt;

# copied
$date = clone $startDt;
```

Comment: I see! Thanks for the help Paul :)